# Weakest possible null hypothesis property

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Is there a name for the following property of a null hypothesis :

$\bar{H0}\implies \forall \alpha\in]0,1], \forall \beta\in]0,1], \exists K\in \mathbb{N},  n>K=>P(p_{value}<\alpha)>1-\beta$ 
 (In other words when n tends towards $+\infty$, not rejecting $H0$ is equivalent to accept it.)

This could be called "weakest possible" but I do not find a reference with such a name.

A counter example: for Mann-Whithney rank sum test a commonly used $H0$ is "*X and Y follow the same arbitrary distribution*". However, for example if X and Y follow two gaussian distributions with the same average and different standard deviation, even if $P(p_{value}<\alpha)>\alpha$, when $n->\infty$, $P(p_{value}<\alpha) < k(\alpha) < 1$

Some other sources, says that there is a preliminary hypothesis that the two distributions are the same, except of a shift, and then the $H0$ is "the shift is $0$", on this case $H0$ is well a "weakest possible".

Comment: Your post seems a bit unclear. Are you talking about null hypotheses or also specific tests? Can you cite an example where what you are trying to describe is mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for you comment. This problem is general to any test, But for a specific test there is several way to define hypotheses. With some of them this property is not true. Actually, I never see this problem explicited in any reference and this is why I looking for the name of it. It is commonly admit that when n tends towards +∞, not rejecting H0 is equivalent to accept it, but this is not true under all H0 and I guess someone else have already assess this problem.